# Reading multiple text files and separating them into different arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matlab

I have this code in MATLAB

```
txtFiles = dir('*.txt') ; %loads txt files
N = length(txtFiles) ; 

for i = 1:N
    data = importdata(txtFiles(i).name);
    x = data(:,1);
    y(:,i) = data(:,2) ;
end
```

Which takes all 100 of my txt files and creates an array for x then stores the y data in an a separate array where each column corresponds to a different txt file's values.

Is there a similar trick in Python?

this is how the data files are constructed:

```
896.5000000000 0.8694710776
896.7500000000 0.7608314184
897.0000000000 0.6349069122
897.2500000000 0.5092121001
897.5000000000 0.3955858698
```

There are 50 of them and each one has about 1000 rows like this,

My solution so far jams it all into a massive list which is impossible to handle. In MATLAB it adds the second column of each text file to an array and I can easily cycle through them.

This is my solution

```
#%%
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import numpy as np
import glob    

# This can be further shortened, but will result in a less clear code.
# One quality of a pythonic code

# Gets file names and reads them.
data = [open(file).read() for file in glob.glob('*.txt')]

# each block of data has it's line split and is put
# into seperate arrays

# [['data1 - line1', 'data1 - line2'], ['data2 - line1',...]]
data = [block.splitlines() for block in data]

x, y = [], []


# takes each line within each file data
# splits it, and appends to x and y
for file in glob.glob('*.txt'):

    # open the file
    with open(file) as _:

        # read and splitlines
        for line in _.read().splitlines():

            # split the columns
            line = line.split()

            # this splits by the spaces
            # example line: -2000        data1
            # output  = ['-2000', 'data']

            # append to lists
           x.append(line[0])
           y.append(line[1])
```

[image]

Comment: `np.loadtxt` should be able handle that file, giving you a 2d array

Comment: Can you give an example? the array should be n x number of files

Answer (score 0):

Your files are pretty much csv files, and could be read using [`np.loadtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) or [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

But as you did you can extract values from the text yourself, the following will work for any number of columns:

```py
def extract_values(text, sep=" ", dtype=float):
    return (
        np.array(x, dtype=dtype)
        for x in zip(*(l.split(sep) for l in text.splitlines()))
    )
```

Then just concatenate the results in the shape you want:

```py
import pathlib

dir_in = pathlib.Path("files/")

indexes, datas = zip(
    *(
        extract_values(f.read_text())
        for f in sorted(dir_in.glob("*.txt"))
    )
)

index = np.stack(indexes, axis=-1)
data = np.stack(datas, axis=-1)
```

Comment: "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)"

Comment: Maybe first try on a single file `index, data = extract_values(f.read_text())`

Comment: How about if I had a third column in my files?

Comment: It works for an arbitrary number of columns: `col1, col2, col3 = extract_values(Path("data.csv").read_text())`. If you know you have the same datatype for each column, you can convert it to a numpy array with: `np.stack(list(extract_values(Path("filecsv.csv").read_text())), axis=-1)`.